# JavaScript scoping rules possibly being tampered with by jQuery/Ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, post

**Note**: I will specify the workaround I found for this issue, but I still do not understand why the first method did not/does not work for me.

I have a jQuery script for my HTML file that is supposed to send a number to a server via an ajax request. Here is the way my script is laid out:

```
// Beginning of script
var number = 0; //ensure that the variable has global scope

// Send number to server on click of button (which has type 'button' not 'submit') in HTML document
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#button" ).click(function() {
        number = 0; // reset the value of the number every time the button is clicked

        // A function runs here and returns a number, and it has a callback (which gets passed that returned number).
        // Callback is defined as follows:
        function callback(returnedNumber) {
            if (condition == true) {
                alert("Condition passes");
            } else {
                // assign returnedNumber to 'number', then initiate ajax POST request to server
                number = returnedNumber; // just assume returnedNumber is 23
            }

            // Notice that the ajax request is NOT initiated as part of the else statement.
            $.post("test.php", { key: number }, function(data) {
                $( "#resultDiv" ).html(data);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Now here is what the "test.php" file on the server looks like:

```
<?php
    echo var_dump($_POST);
?>
```

When the condition in the callback does not pass, `var_dump()` shows that the value of `$_POST["key"]` is still 0 instead of 23, and this is where I get confused. My understanding of JS scoping rules is that once a variable is declared globally, functions can modify its value as long as the `var` keyword is not used to re-declare the variable within the function. I thought this would mean that using my callback to reassign the value of `number` would also change the value of the global variable `number`, thus allowing me to send it to the server without the ajax request being a part of the else statement that reassigned the variable. So, what part of that do I have wrong? If there is documentation that will help clarify my misunderstanding, please provide a link. `:)`

**My Workaround**: I simply appended the ajax POST request to the else statement, and that worked as I wanted it to. But I do not understand why the ajax request does not take the updated value of `number` when the request is not part of the else statement.

Thanks!

Comment: Where are you calling `callback` function? Secondly, `$.post` is not inside `else`, as you mentioned in your question.

Comment: You are correct about the scoping. What is sent if you never reset the number back to 0?

Comment: @MarcodeZeeuw 0 is sent when I remove the reset line.

Comment: @MilanChheda `callback` is called where I put its definition. I put only the definition so it's clear what `callback` does. A separate function is first called there, and `callback` gets its returned result when the function executes. And yes, `$.post` is not inside `else`. What I want to understand is why that affects the value of `number` sent by `$.post`. Seeing as `number` is a global variable, my expectation was that the updated value of `number` would be sent instead of the initial/reset value `0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in this example, you are right about the scope part, so there must be something else going wrong, probably in the callback. Perhaps you're trying to get the number in an async-way, posting the data before you've gotten a response?

```js
var condition = false;
var number = 0; //ensure that the variable has global scope

$("#button").click(function() {
  number = 0; // reset the value of the number every time the button is clicked
  function callback(returnedNumber) {
    if (condition == true) {
      //alert("Condition passes");
    } else {
      // assign returnedNumber to 'number', then initiate ajax POST request to server
      number = 23; // just assume returnedNumber is 23
    }
    condition = !condition;
    $("#result").text(`Result: ${number}. Setting condition to ${condition}`);
  }
  // Call the callback as an actual callback
  setTimeout(callback, 1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button">Click...</button>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: That must be it. The function I'm using to obtain the new number is indeed asynchronous - the Google Maps API Distance Matrix Service. This is my first time seeing (and now understanding) the practical difference between a synchronous and asynchronous call, so I'm very grateful that you've helped shine light on this. Thanks!